# Change this element when its not the selector in the function?

Tags: jquery

All I am trying to achieve here is applying changes to `breakoff` at the same time changes are applied to `this` which is `jQuery('.toggle-bg')`

**jQuery** *I am trying to only make changes to `breakoff` from  `this` `.toggle-bg`*

```
    jQuery('.toggle-bg').on('change', function () {

    var value = jQuery('input.switch-id-value',this).val(),
    moon1 = jQuery('#' + value + '_0').is(':checked'),
    breakoff = jQuery('.line-break-off'),
    toggle = jQuery(this);

        toggle.css('background-color', (moon1 ? '#46b692' : '#333'));

        breakoff.each(function() {
            toggle.css('background-color', (moon1 ? '#46b692' : '#333'));
        });

}).trigger('change');
```

There are several things I am sure that will get this to work... example I would need to use `.parent()` Let me show you the HTML so you understand where `breakoff` is in relation to the toggle.

HTML:

```
    <li class="top-header">

        <div class="box-title">
            <div class="section-icon fontawesome-twitter">
            <span class="line-decor"></span>
            <span class="line-break-off break"></span> //THE TARGET
            </div>
        </div>

// This is sloppy but this block below contains the toggle you get the idea.. 
// I dont have much experience using .parent() it kinda confuses me
// I am sure I need to nest my way out to target this.parent() .line-break-off

<div class="party">
    <div class="control-block ">
        <fieldset class="buttonset button-switch"><span class="toggle-bg" id="top-header" style="background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="brashup[top-header]" id="top-header_0"><input type="hidden" value="top-header" class="switch-id-value"><input type="radio" value="0" name="brashup[top-header]" id="top-header_1"><input type="hidden" value="top-header" class="switch-id-value"><span class="switch ui-buttonset"><p class="switch-inner-bar"></p></span></span>
        </fieldset>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <div class="bottom-box"><span class="description btn-desc">Here you can choose if you want a fixed header or not.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
```

Simply put, this is a list of multiple toggles and while the specific toggle is changed I want to manipulate its parent `.line-break-off` by adding a class, or css whatever I can take it from there :)

Comment: I'm sure you tried but it's still phrased in a very confusing way - maybe try reading it yourself and seeing if you understand it and polish it if you haven't already? If you had to explain it to a 10 year old - what you _want_ to happen, how would you do it? A fiddle on jsfiddle.net also helps pretty often.

Comment: Ok sorry after reading my question I did make it more confusing and complicated than what it really is.. I updated the first sentence of the question. *All I am trying to achieve here is applying changes to breakoff at the same time changes are applied to this which is jQuery('.toggle-bg')*

Comment: breakoff is just a var of jQuery('line-break-off')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following. `breakoff` should be something like this:

```
breakoff = jQuery(this).parents(".top-header").find('.line-break-off')
```

and then:

```
breakoff.each(function() {
    jQuery(this).css('background-color', (moon1 ? '#46b692' : '#333'));
});
```

Comment: I think I wrote something like this and it applied to all the elements.. let me try this again.. Also using that if else syntax how do I use it with `.addClass` I made an attempt but failed

Comment: Oh changing the `breakoff` var to that might fix it.. it sounds right.. brb

Comment: Yes now I can maniplulate my breakoff var however I want.. looks cool now, but could you possibly provide an example using that if else syntax with adding a class instead of css? I did something like `breakoff.addClass((moon1 ? 'class1' : 'class2'));` but it added both

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry didn't understand your last question, do you want to add a class depending on the moon1 variable?

Comment: Yes you got it... not quite sure.. maybe I should just toggle the class? In my mind that wouldnt match whether the toggle button was on or off though? So yes I would need to follow the moon1 variable

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry, Ok, you can use this line `jQuery(this).toggleClass("red", moon1).toggleClass("yellow",!moon1);`. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rf90210/NpzLs/3/ and uses a better sintax for the `breakoff` finding

Comment: Ok thanks working with variables is cool, nice to learn this, I would have wrote it long hand like if(moon1 == true){} else blah this saves space..